# Serialize String-collection object for storing in session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, serialization, stringcollection

In my ASP.Net application, I'm storing a string collection in a Session variable. It was working fine but now I want to change session settings from in-proc to Out Proc. Now I'm having an issue that "Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session". How can I serialize the Sting Collection object before assigning it to a session variable? Please help.

```
Session["SelectedItems"] =customerGroupsList.SelectedItemsCollection;
```

I want to change above line of code.

Comment: It's obvious that `SelectedItemsCollection` is non-serializable, you'll have to create a POCO for this, and serialize to/from it most likely. Alternatively, you may try serializing with JSON.NET (whatever generic JSON serializer you like) and storing the serialized string to the session-state variable.

Comment: What about Instead of assigning StringCollection types to the session, derive a class out of StringCollection, make it serializable and use that class object to assign to the session. is there any issue?

Comment: Are you sure `SelectedItemsCollection` is actually a [`StringCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Because `StringCollection` is in fact marked with `[SerializableAttribute]` according to the documentation.  Possibly it's some internal subclass, or something else entirely?

Comment: Its a StringCollection only. `public StringCollection SelectedItemsCollection
        {
            get { return dataGridController.SelectedCheckBoxItemsCollection; }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

If it's just really a string collection object, then you case use the code below to serialize it and store it as String:

```
        Session["SelectedItems"] = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(customerGroupsList.SelectedItemsCollection);
```

Comment: This will make a lot of changes in my application.It's required to deserialize every time I use that session variable. Is it possible to do like this? Instead of assigning StringCollection types to session, derive a class out of StringCollection, make it serializable and use that class object to assign to the session